# How do I write these htaccess rules as one rule instead of multiple?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rules in my htaccess. one is for the main domain of the server and the others are other domains that are pointed at the server.

the purpose is to redirect subdomains to a url that is written a certain way. the main domain excludes certain subdomains from the redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|mydev|something|somethingelse)\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://maindomain.com/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=maindomain.com [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.anotherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.anotherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=anotherdomain.com [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.whatever\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.whatever\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://whatever.com/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=whatever.com [QSA,L]
```

I don't want to keep having to add a new 3 lines for each new domain pointed at the server. How do I create one rule set to incorporate any domain that is pointed at the server?  I would still need certain subdomains to be excluded from the main domain, but it wouldn't matter if the same subdomains are excluded from all the domains.

here are a couple things I tried. neither works.

```
#attempt 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.|)([a-z0-9-]+)\.(.+\.(?:[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]+))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=%2 [QSA,L]

#attempt 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|mydev|something|somethingelse)\.(.+\.(?:[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]+))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=%2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Since you have different target URLs in each of the rule, so it cannot be combined into one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I solved it, but this seems to be working. not sure if i can make it even better to handle http and https at the same time, and to handle many exceptions for main domain but just the one exception for the rest, but this is satisfactory enough for my needs. most domains will be ssl, so only need to edit htaccess files to add non ssl domains.

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove www from any domain pointed at box whether it's ssl or not
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#main domain with subdomain exceptions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydev\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^something\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^somethingelse\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=maindomain.com [L,R]

#non ssl domains here. three lines each.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.anotherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.anotherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://anotherdomain.com/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=anotherdomain.com [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.whatever\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.whatever\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://whatever.com/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=whatever.com [L,R]

#all ssl domains use this one rule.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+\.(?:[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]+))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+\.(?:[a-z]{2}\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]+))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=%2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If anyone can improve it, can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: i mean so that i don't have to edit htaccess for non ssl domains as well.